# Is a metric space perfectly normal?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separation-axioms

I typically like to practice my knowledge on a specific concept by doing proofs using one definition of a term, and then doing the same proofs using an equivalent definition (without inducing the equivalence). However, I'm stuck on the following:

We say that a topological space $(S,T)$ is *perfectly normal* if for every closed set $F\subseteq S$ there is a continuous function $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $F=\{x\in S:f(x)=0\}$.

Can we prove that a metric space is perfectly normal by this definition?

I've seen some posts ([post 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72138/why-are-these-two-definitions-of-a-perfectly-normal-space-equivalent), [post 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72233/does-perfectly-normal-implies-normal)) where this just follows as a corollary. More specifically, it follows by the equivalence of definitions and the results that metric spaces are normal and $G_\delta$. However, I'm wondering if there was a more direct approach, as opposed to such a roundabout method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For all nonempty $A \subset X$ the function “least distance to $A$” given by $$x \mapsto \operatorname{dist}{(x,A)} = \inf\limits_{a \in A}\;d(x,a)$$ is continuous (even $1$-Lipschitz) and it is zero precisely on the closure of $A$, [see this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48850/) for some proofs of that fact.

If $A \neq \emptyset$ is closed then $A = \{x \in X\,:\,\operatorname{dist}(x,A) = 0\}$.
If $A = \emptyset$ take a constant non-zero function.

Comment: Great construction! I hadn't even considered doing a constructive proof since I thought it would be too hard. I was merely hoping that out of the definitions, I could somehow "pop out" the subtle existence of one. But this is much better!