# Nonnormal spaces cannot be metrizable.

Tags: general-topology

Why are nonnormal spaces not metrizable?

It's a statement I found on wikipedia that I need to understand. When looking at the metrization theorems I don't see any obvious connections.  Is this result trivial or not?

Comment: In other words: Why are metric spaces normal?  The question seems simpler that way.

Comment: Also see this thread: [Is a metric space perfectly normal?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/73609)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s an immediate consequence of the fact that every metric space is normal, which follows readily from the non-trivial fact that every metric space is paracompact.

**Added:** I just realized that one can avoid paracompactness quite easily. Let $\langle X,d\rangle$ be a metric space, and let $H$ and $K$ be disjoint, non-empty closed subsets of $X$. Now let

$$f:X\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\frac{d(x,H)}{d(x,H)+d(x,K)}\;;$$

this is a continuous real-valued function separating $H$ and $K$, showing that $X$ is not just normal, but perfectly normal.

Comment: Is that the most common route (through paracompact) to showing that a metric space is normal?

Comment: @user41728: Yes, at least in my experience.

Comment: @user41728: But there are other, more elementary ways, and I just thought of one.